# What is the difference between [0,1,2,3,4] and [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of years and multiply this with a factor 2 and get the result:

```
years = [0,1,2,3,4] 
x = [[2*i] for i in years]
result = [[0],[2],[4],[6],[8]]
```

However, I would like to divide this by the sum of the result, but I seems like it is not possible.

Therefore, what is the difference between [0,1,2,3,4] and [[0],[2],[4],[6],[8]]?
And how can I change the format so it is possible to divide each number in the result list by the sum of the results?

Comment: Why `[2*i]` instead of just `2*i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` is a list of integers. It's a one-dimensional list and you only need one index to access its elements. For example, `years[3]` is the integer `3`.

`[[0],[2],[4],[6],[8]]` is a list of lists of integers, so it's a two-dimensional list. You need two indices to access its integer elements. For example, `result[3]` will give you the list `[6]`, and the zeroth index of *that list* will give you the integer `6`. In other words, `result[3][0]` gives you the integer `6`.

The list comprehension `result = [[2*i] for i in years]` is what creates the two-dimensional list because you *asked it to*. You said:

- For every `i` in `years`,

  - Calculate `2 * i`
  - Put that into a list `[2 * i]`
- Collect all these lists of `[2 * i]` in a single list.

If you wanted a 1-d list, skip the brackets around `[2 * i]` like so: `result = [2 * i for i in years]`. This tells Python to:

- For every `i` in `years`,

  - Calculate `2 * i`
- Collect all these `2 * i` into a single list